# Javascript missing semicolon?

Tags: javascript

So I am using jsfiddle.net to test my javascript code. I am working with google maps API but that doesn't really matter with respect to my question. Once I added this function:

```
function testCoord(points) {
    var result = false;

    for (var i = 0, var j = points.length - 1; i < points.length; j = i++) {
        if ((points[i].latLng.lat() > testCoord[0].latLng.lat()) != (points[j].latLng.lat() >
 testCoord[0].latLng.lat()) && (testCoord[0].latLng.lng() < (points[j].latLng.lng() -
 points[i].latLng.lng()) * (testCoord[0].latLng.lat() - points[i].latLng.lat()) /
 (points[j].latLng.lat() - points[i].latLng.lat()) + points[i].latLng.lng())) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I use the JSHint tool it tells me I'm missing a semicolon on the for loop line and when I call `break` it says its unexpected. I really don't think I am missing any semicolons, but something is wrong because not the map doesn't display, even though I never call the function. Am I not allowed to declare the for loop with both i and j? I am lost after struggling with this for hours...

Comment: `var i=0, j=points.length-1; ...`  Only 1 `var` required.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer so no spaces?

Comment: Eliminate the `var` token that's before `j`

Comment: @Michael The spaces don't matter. Just write whatever is easier to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `var` in both places.

```
for (var i = 0, j = points.length - 1; i < points.length; j = i++)
```

Comment: haha I should have noticed that. I was busy looking for something bigger.

Comment: Or don't declare multiple variables in a `for` at all. This is maintainability hell...

Comment: @Ben it's a demo I'll use probably once. Has no other purpose and is easier to translate algorithm this way IMO, but good point.

Answer (score 0):

Try your code with `for (var i = 0, j = points.length - 1; ...`. Avoid using `var x = ..., var y = ...`.